# Detect Element's Children as Numeric Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiddle: http://liveweave.com/Aq56fN

In my fiddle I have a div that has a few elements as it's children. Is there anyway to detect how many children an element has as a numeric value? If so how would something like this be done?

**JavaScript/JQuery**:

```
$(".grab-contenu").on('click', function() {
  $(".spectacle-contenu").html(
    $(".contenu").children().toString()
  );
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="contenu" align="center">
  <header class="largeur-objet">My width is 80%</header>
  <button class="grab-contenu">Detect children number</button>
  <footer class="spectacle-contenu">Show children number</footer>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
$(".contenu").children().toString()
```

To

```
$(".contenu").children().length
```

Comment: [`.length` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/length/)